# Deserialize XML Elements which are under same node into 2 different Object

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xml-deserialization

```
<root>
  <x_Name />
  <x_Age />
  <x_Gender />
  <x_addr1 />
  <x_addr2 />
  <x_city />
  <x_state />
  <x_country />
  <x_zip />
</root>
```

The above sample xml, I would like to deserialize the content into 2 objects such as Personal details that include (name, Age, and gender) and Contact Details that include (address details).

I could able to deserialize all the contect  into a single object but I am unable to split into into 2 objects using xml deserialization.

Comment: Xml Serialization will not split a tag into two different elements (unless using a custom method).  If you are going to use Xml Serialization do the splitting after the classes are created.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.8) to deserialize the xml into 2 seperate classes.

1. Create the 2 models:

   ```
   [XmlRoot("root", Namespace = "")]
   public class Personal
   {
       [XmlElement("x_Name", Namespace = "")]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       [XmlElement("x_Age", Namespace = "")]
       public string Age { get; set; }
   }


   [XmlRoot("root", Namespace = "")]
   public class Contact
   {
       [XmlElement("x_country", Namespace = "")]
       public string Country { get; set; }

       [XmlElement("x_zip", Namespace = "")]
       public string Zip { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Create a simple generic function that deserializes the class.

   ```
   class Program
   {
       private static string _xml = @"c:\temp\myxml.xml";

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var personal = Deserialize<Personal>(_xml);
           var contact = Deserialize<Contact>(_xml);
       }

       public static T Deserialize<T>(string file)
       {
           var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

           using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(file))            
               return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);            
       }
   }
   ```